# How to use initState from another file on flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to import the information of `initState` that stores the state of my `Switch`.

The problem is that `initState` is on my homepage file and I want to import it from my "error page".

**Example:**

- If my `Switch` is on, my theme will change.
- I want to import that Switch info (boolean) on every page of my app.
- I want to be able to change that `Switch` value on other pages too.

Here is my homepage:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State\<MyHomePage\> {
bool isSwitchedFT = false;
void updateSwitchValue(bool newValue)
  {
    setState(() {
      isSwitchedFT = newValue;
    });
  }

@override
void initState(){
super.initState();
getSwitchValues();
}
getSwitchValues() async {
isSwitchedFT = (await getSwitchState())!;
setState(() {});
}

Future <bool> saveSwitchState(bool value) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
return prefs.setBool("switchState", value);
}

Future <bool?> getSwitchState() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool? isSwitchedFT = prefs.getBool("switchState");

    return isSwitchedFT;

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(){...}
```

**And here is my other page:**

```dart
class _ErrorPageState extends State<ErrorPage> {

/// I want to get this boolean info from MyHomePage initState
   bool isSwitchedFT = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(...);
```

Here is my Switch:

```
Switch(
                  value: isSwitchedFT,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isSwitchedFT = value;
                      saveSwitchState(value);
                      //switch works
                    });
                  })
```

this is my complete code from the second page:

```
class SubmitErrorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubmitErrorPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: ErrorPage(),
    );
  }
}

class ErrorPage extends StatefulWidget {


  const ErrorPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ErrorPage> createState() => ErrorPageState();
}

class ErrorPageState extends State<ErrorPage> {


  bool isSwitchedFT = true;

  GlobalKey<MyHomePageState> myKey = GlobalKey();
  //get the value of the switch
  bool getSwitchValueFromHomePage()
  {
    return myKey.currentState!.isSwitchedFT;
  }
  //update the switch
  void updateSwitchValue(bool newValue)
  {
    myKey.currentState!.updateSwitchValue(newValue); // you need to implement this function in your MyHomePageState
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: isSwitchedFT ? Colors.black : Colors.white,){...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you access the variable from your state using `GlobalKey` like:

```
 static GlobalKey<MyHomePageState> myKey = GlobalKey();

 myKey.currentState!.isSwitchedFT; //here
```

where you have to remove the `_` part from your state to be accessible.

edit: the logic in your code would look something like:

```
class _ErrorPageState extends State<ErrorPage> {

  /// I want to get this boolean info from MyHomePage initState
  bool isSwitchedFT = false;
  GlobalKey<MyHomePageState> myKey = GlobalKey();
  //get the value of the switch 
  bool getSwitchValueFromHomePage()
  {
    return myKey.currentState!.isSwitchedFT;
  }
  //update the switch
  void updateSwitchValue(bool newValue)
  {
    myKey.currentState!.updateSwitchValue(newValue); // you need to implement this function in your MyHomePageState
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(...);
  }
}
```

the `updateSwitchValue` would look like:

```
void updateSwitchValue(bool newValue)
{
  setState(() {
       this.isSwitchedFT = newValue;
    });
}
```

and you need to add it to your `MyHomePageState`.

Comment: Can you apply that change on my code, please?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea how can I implement that function on `_MyHomePageState` you said?

Comment: glad to help, i added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but now i'm having this problem on my error page: `The name '_MyHomePageState' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.`  Any idea?

Comment: I just realized this, you need to remove the '_' part from your state to access it, since `_` in flutter means that this state is private.

Comment: The code looks fine but still not working :/ Do I need to put something on my `Switch` value or `onChanged`?

Comment: what scenario did you exactly test?

Comment: I enter the home page, and turn the switch on, so i can know if it changed the other page, and then i press my button to go to another page, on that page the value comes from the `bool isSwitchedFT = false;` from it page's code. I'm testing on my android device.

Comment: are you reading the switch value in your 'other page' from the home page's state or from the other page's own `isSwitchedFT`  variable ?

Comment: It looks that is getting from the 'other page' statement: `bool isSwitchedFT = false;`, not from homepage state (from where i need). I've updated the codes from the 2 pages so we can see where is the problem.

Comment: you should  remove `bool isSwitchedFT = false;` and get the switch value using the `getSwitchValueFromHomePage` function.  and in case your value need to be read and changed from multiple places I recommend you to switch your code to use some state management methods,  for more information about that, I recommend you to read this:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options